# Discrete Mathematics Probability Review Question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Can someone please explain why the following question's answer is (a)?

Assume that a newborn baby is a girl with probability p and a boy with probability 1 − p.
Also assume that the genders of different newborns are independent of each other. Consider
a person who has two children.

Define the following two events:

A = “both children are girls”

B = “at least one of the children is a girl”

What is the conditional probability Pr(A | B)?

(a) p/(2−p)

(b) (2−p)/p

(c) p

(d) 1/p

Answer (score 1):

Probability that both children are girls
$$P(A)=p^2$$

Probability that at least one child is a girl (both girls, only first child girl, only second child girl)
$$P(B) = p^2 + p(1-p) + (1-p)p=p(2-p)$$

Conditional probability
$$P(A\vert B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{p}{2-p}$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of two girls is $p(A)=p^2$. The probability of at least one girl is one minus the probability of two boys, so $p(B)=1-(1-p)^2=2p-p^2$. The probability of two girls given one girl is 
$$
p(A|B)={p(A,B)\over p(B)}.
$$
However, $p(A,B)=p(A)$ since we can't have two girls unless there is at least one. Thus
$$
p(A|B)={p^2\over 2p-p^2}={p\over 2-p}.
$$